# How can get data from object in php

Tags: php, oop

I have an object so i want to know how can get data from object.Object example is given below

```
return $response= PowerConsumption::groupBY('device_id')
            ->selectRaw('round(sum(unit),4) as yAxis,device_id')
           ->where('created_at',Carbon::now())->paginate(1);
```

So this eloquent query create given data,but i need current_page and please don't change my query.Only help me to figure out current_page value from this response.

```
{
total: 2,
per_page: 1,
current_page: 1,
last_page: 2,
next_page_url: "http://localhost:8000/graph/monthly/user_id/2?page=2",
prev_page_url: null,
from: 1,
to: 1,
data: [
{
yAxis: 222.8572,
device_id: 1
}
]
}
```

This data is store in $response variable and i need only current_page and last_page so how can i get.
i'm trying this like

```
$response['current_page']; //it's return null
$response->current_page; //it's return error like
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$current_page
```

Kindly help me in getting data

Comment: Your `$response` isn't what you think it is. It is a [`LengthAwarePaginator`](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html). Perhaps it _contains_ a response object?

Comment: can you show `var_dump($response);` ?

Comment: $resonse->current_page; <==== You missing character [p]

Comment: I edit my question so please check again and help me

Answer (score 0):

Simply use PHP object-access notation to get any data you want from your object as shown below... however, notice that you have a Typo in your code `$response->current_page` not `$resonse->current_page;` as @Quỳnh Nguyễn noted in his comment above.

```
<?php

    /*
    YOUR $response, AS A PHP OBJECT, COULD BE REPRESENTED WITH THE OBJECT VARIABLE; $response BELOW
    {
    total: 2,
    per_page: 1,
    current_page: 1,
    last_page: 2,
    next_page_url: "http://localhost:8000/user/user_id/2?page=2",
    prev_page_url: null,
    from: 1,
    to: 1,
   } 
   */

    $response                 = new stdClass();
    $response->total          = 2;
    $response->per_page       = 1;
    $response->current_page   = 1;
    $response->last_page      = 2;
    $response->next_page_url  = "http://localhost:8000/user/user_id/2?page=2";
    $response->next_page_url  = null;
    $response->from           = 1;
    $response->to             = 1;

    // NOW TO GET THE current_page, you could do:
    $response->current_page;
```

> It is probable that you are using Laravel... if so, this is what your controller might look like:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    use App\Http\Requests;

    class PowerController extends Controller{

        public function power(){ 
            $response = PowerConsumption::groupBY('device_id')
                                        ->selectRaw('round(sum(unit),4) as yAxis,device_id')
                                        ->where('created_at',Carbon::now())->paginate(1);
            // YOU SHOULD RETURN VIEW INSIDE YOUR METHOD
            // AND PASS THE $response AS ARGUMENT...

            return view('your_view_name', compact($response));              
        }
    }
```

> Now in your view; you should be able to access your data much like any normally declared variable:

```
//your_view_name.blade.php
{{ $current_page }}
{{ $next_page_url }}
{{ $prev_page_url }}
{{ $total }}
```

Comment: you didn't complete your answer.

Comment: @MarkoMackic    Sorry... accidentally deleted it before posting... had to redo it again :-(

Comment: I edit my question so please check again and help me